# Renaming filename before first occurrence of character

Tags: bash, filenames

I'm trying to rename a batch of files using a bash script or just in the command line but can't seem to find anything on how to remove characters before the first occurrence of a character.

Right now my files are named:

```
author1_-_year_-_title_name.txt
author2_-_year_-_title_name.txt
```

And I want them to look like

```
_-_year_-_title_name.text
```

or even

```
year_-_title_name.text
```

I've tried sed in the command line:

```
sed 's/^[^_-_]* _-_ //' *
```

but this only tried to edit the text files, not the file name

Comment: You can do it with shell builtin string manipulation: `old='author1_-_year_-_title_name.txt'; new="${old#*_-_}"; echo "$new"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change filenames using `sed`. Try this simple loop instead:

```
for fp in ./*_-_*; do
  echo mv "$fp" "${fp#*_-_}"
done
```

If the output looks good, remove `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try `rename` command as follows.

```
rename -n s/[^-]*-_//  *.txt
```

Output will be as follows.

```
rename(author1_-_year_-_title_name.txt, year_-_title_name.txt)
rename(author2_-_year_-_title_name.txt, year_-_title_name.txt)
```

Once you are Happy with above results(which will print only on terminal) remove `-n` option in above command and it should rename the files.